# export env variables programmatically, via stdout of command

Tags: bash, shell-script

Ok so instead of hardcoding some local env variables that mirror a remote server (OpenShift server), I'd like to programmatically do it, so we don't have to keep everything up-to-date manually.

Right now I have this hardcoded in a file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_USERNAME="admin"
export OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD="xyz"
export OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST="emsa-xyz-2-emsa.cloudapps.nabisco.com"
export OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT=60161
```

Instead of hardcoding, I can retrieve the "public" env variables from OpenShift with this command:

```
rhc env list -a <app-name>
```

which writes this to stdout:

```
NODE_ENV=jailbreak
NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST=emsa-xyz-2-emsa.cloudapps.nabisco.com
OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD=xyz
OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT=60161
OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_USERNAME=admin
```

does anyone know how I can take that stdout, and, in turn, export each of those variables?

I assume it would be like so - get each line and then put `export` in front of it and then run `bash -e "export x"`...the problem is that probably runs in a subshell and wouldn't effect the current shell?

The existing answer to this question is good and should not be lost.

Comment: Right but the answer given to this question is probably better than the answers given to the other question, at least it's more thorough in explanation.

Comment: If this is a dupe question, it's a super dupe question if you ask me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have trust in the output of your rhc command, you can just source it:

```
. <(rhc env list -a <app-name>)
```

This will source (execute) each line that `rhc` produces.

As written, the code above defines the variables but doesn't export them.  We could fix that but the code below is safer and does the exporting.

The source command, `.`, expects a file as an argument.  To convert the output of `rhc` into a file-like object, we use *process substitution*: `<(...)`.

To be more secure, use:

```
while read -r line; do declare -x "$line"; done < <(rhc env list -a <app-name>)
```

Here, we use process substitution, `<(...)`, combined with input redirection, `<`, so that the `while` loop reads from the output of `rhc`.  The space between the first and second `<` is essential: do **not** omit it.

The `-x` option to `declare` tells bash to *export* the variable.

#### Changing order

As per comment below, the `rhc` command can be placed on the line above the `while` loop via:

```
tmpvar=$(rhc env list -a <app-name>)
while read -r line; do declare -x "$line"; done <<<"$tmpvar"
```

`<<<` creates a *here string*.  In this case, it means the `$tmpvar` is provided as input to the `while` loop.

Comment: Nice very cool, there is no manual entry for declare - `man declare` doesn't seem to exist at least on my MacOS machine, wonder how it works so that it acts as `export`

Comment: @AlexanderMills `declare` is a bash builtin.  To get help on it, run `help declare` or else open up `man bash` and look at the section entitled `SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS`.

Comment: Do you know of a way to put the `rhc` command on the line above the while loop?

Comment: For now, I am guessing just store it in a variable and it should work.

Comment: @AlexanderMills Yes, that can be done with a variable.  See the new section at the end of the updated answer.

Comment: thanks, I have never seen `<<<` before, what is that operator?

Comment: I will have to look up how `<<<` works compared to `< <()`

Comment: @AlexanderMills `< <(...)` takes the output of the command inside the parens and provides it as input to the `while` loop.  By contrast, `<<<` takes the contents of the string that follows (in this case, the contents of `$tmpvar`) and provides it as input to the `while` loop.  `<<<` is called a _here string_ and is documented in `man bash`.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something: why not just pipe in to the read command? As in `rhc env list -a <app-name> | while read -r line; do declare -x "$line"; done`

Comment: It appears that I am missing something; my comment above does not work, though I can't figure out why.

Comment: @Jasha The processes in a pipeline are in _subshells_.  Any variable created in one of the subshells will cease to exist once the pipeline exits.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. Thanks for the explanation!